# Sample projects implementing a specific technology

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

is it acceptable to ask a question similar to:

- "I'm a noob in "technology X", Can I have a list of opensource large scale projects that implement MVC / OOP / MV using that technology"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acceptable? Depends entirely on the audience. Useful? No.

The problems with such questions is that they are not actionable. The industry is at a point where you can spend your entire life chasing technologies, buzzwords, and acronyms without ever achieving anything. Any web search on "Technology X" will reveal a bottomless pit of projects, articles, proposals, people, and delusional wankery.

Stack Overflow works because it is a Q & A site, not a discussion forum on the latest nerd fad. "I'm a noob" is not a question. "Technology X" is not a question. I suppose "can I have a list" is a question, but the answer is always the same; "yes". The problem is lists are seldom helpful.

It is not evident from such a question what the asker is trying to do. Once the asker has such a list (or more likely, several), how are they to implement it? How are they to determine which is the "right" list?

Such questions only promote discussion. Not that discussion is bad, but it's not a question and there isn't a correct answer to them.

Comment: +1 for the third paragraph. I wonder if I'll ever see the term "delusional wankery" again.